# controller#index method showing routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

i'm new to ruby on rails. 
I've set up a resources directive in the routes file.

```
resources :employees
```

Which creates the following routes

```
 root        /                                    employees#index
 employees     GET      /employees(.:format)          employees#index
              POST     /employees(.:format)          employees#create
 new_employee GET  /employees/new(.:format)      employees#new
 edit_employee GET  /employees/:id/edit(.:format) employees#edit
 employee     GET      /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#show
              PUT      /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#update
              DELETE   /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#destroy
```

But when I put /employees in to the address bar I get

```
No route matches {:controller=>"employees", :action=>"show"}
```

Even though /employees should call employees#index not employees#show

Wham am i missing here?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you haven't implemented employees#show, have you?

Comment: Does it work with other routes or a different name?

Comment: @tadman - All the other routes work. pavel I have, but employees#show should be called on /employees/:id

Comment: Same problem if you go to the "/employees.html" or "/employees.json" addresses?

Comment: No, it works fine with the json and xml addresses. html shows same error

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code in the index action of the EmployeesController?

Comment: Are you displaying an HTML page for index, that has a link to show on it? The error would be given when trying to generate the link.

Comment: Paste the whole routes file. I bet it's an order thing. To me it looks like rails thinks your using resource instead of resources... unless you are mucking elsewhere down the file. and put root at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a link in the layout or template like **employee_path** (not **employees_path**).
And you have got this error.